# How to grep matching string with 1st column?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I am trying to get only matching strings (`match_E2` and `pattern_2`) along with 1st column.

```
abcd.corp;;a123,Virtual,aws,Linux,Linux,match_E2,Database
web1.corp;;,Virtual,azure,match_E2,Linux,corpo,Database
web2.corp;;match_E2,Virtual,a2responsible,Linux_Suse,Linux,corpo,Database
web3.corp;;Virtual,Virtual,corpo,pattern_2,Linux,corpo,Database
web4.corp;;Virtual,Virtual,corpo,,Linux,pattern_2,Database
```

expected output could be below

```
abcd.corp,match_E2
web1.corp,match_E2
web2.corp,match_E2
web3.corp,pattern_2
web4.corp,pattern_2
```

I tried to use option `-o` in `grep` but it gives only matching strings.

Comment: Does it have to be `grep`, or is `awk` also an option? Your question tags seem to indicate this, just want to make sure. Also, how exactly are the patterns defined. Are the simple strings or regular expressions? Are they always the same for one processing run, or are you looking for multiple matches to be found in one pass? Also, do you actually have mixed delimiters (`;` _and_ `,`), and if so, can the match occur only in the `,`-separated part?

Comment: anything either awk or grep or both would be ok, but more i am preferring in one line command, pattern is similar what i mentioned

Comment: The problem is you mentioned _two_ patterns. Do you want to look for both in one single run of the command you are looking for, or is it okay to call the command twice (i.e. once for each search pattern). Also, is it ensured that the pattern can occur only once on every line, or could there be multiple occurences on the same line?

Comment: yes, pattern occurs only once in every line either match_E2 or pattern_2  or none. But not both at a time .

Comment: Does `mismatch_E2` match `match_E2`? What about `pattern_275` matching `pattern_2`? You said you wanted to match 2 strings but accepted an answer that matches 2 partial regexps - just confirming that a partial regexp match is **really** what you wanted rather than a full string match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I daresay your case might be better handled with `sed`.

For `match_E2` pattern:

```
$ sed -nE 's/^([^;]+).*(match_E2).*/\1,\2/p' file.txt
```

For `pattern_2` pattern:

```
$ sed -nE 's/^([^;]+).*(pattern_2).*/\1,\2/p' file.txt
```

For both those patterns in one go:

```
$ sed -nE 's/^([^;]+).*(match_E2|pattern_2).*/\1,\2/p' file.txt
```

That is, basically:

```
$ sed -nE 's/^([^;]+).*(    ).*/\1,\2/p' file.txt
#                       ^  ^
#                       |  |
#            ---------------------
# put within these two parentheses the same (Extended Regular Expression) pattern you would use with `grep -E`
```

Note that it only relies on at least one `;` being the separator between the first field and the rest of the line.

Answer (score 4):

The following `awk` command should do what you want:

```
awk -F'[;,]' -v pat="match_E2" '$0~pat{for (i=3;i<NF;i++) {if ($i ~ pat) printf("%s,%s\n",$1,$i)}}' file.txt
```

- The `-F'[;,]'` option will tell `awk` to recognize both `;` and `,` as field separator and split the line accordingly. *Note that while the POSIX standard mandates that such a multi-character field separator is interpreted as full regular expressions, there may still be `awk` versions around that don't implement this correctly.*
- The pattern is passed to awk via the `-v pat="match_E2"` command-line option. *Note that this will interpret the pattern as full regular expression. If you have characters in there that have a special meaning in this context, you need to escape them!*
- If the current line matches the pattern (`$0 ~ pat` means "if the entire line matches the regular expression stored in `pat` somewhere"), it will loop over all relevant fields (field 3 is the first field after the last `;`) and identify the one that actually matched (the `if ($i ~ pat)` condition). It then prints the first field (`$1`) and the matching field (`$i`) via `printf()`. *This assumes that there can only be one such field on a matching line*!

If you look for multiple patterns, you can either formulate the regular expression in `pat` accordingly, as in

```
awk -F'[;,]' -v pat="match_E2|pattern_2" ' ... etc ... '
```

or run the command twice, once for each pattern.

Comment: Thanks @AdminBee , it works as expected. Can you please explain line - '$0~pat{for (i=2;i<NF;i++) {if ($i ~ pat) printf("%s,%s\n",$1,$i)}}'

Comment: @Sin15 I edited the answer to include more explanation. You may want to look at the [GNU awk user's guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) for more insight if you are interested.

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat more `grep -o` like awk version, using the `match` function:

```
$ awk -F';' 'match($0,/match_E2|pattern_2/) {print $1 "," substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file
abcd.corp,match_E2
web1.corp,match_E2
web2.corp,match_E2
web3.corp,pattern_2
web4.corp,pattern_2
```

Comment: could you please explain your command..

Answer (score 1):

Best I can offer is a very VERY ugly workaround:

```
# Finds first columns
first=(`grep "match_E2" text | awk -F';;' '{print $1}'`)

# Lets join them together now
for column in ${first[@]}; do
  echo "$column,match_E2"
done
```

Result:

```
abcd.corp,match_E2
web1.corp,match_E2
web2.corp,match_E2
```

You can also make a script or function and replace serach string with $1, and then call it with search string as argument. Like this:

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
first=(`grep "$1" text | awk -F';;' '{print $1}'`)
for column in ${first[@]}; do
  echo "$column,$1"
done
```

And then you call it like this:

```
xxxx@ubuntu:~/test# ./script.sh match_E2
abcd.corp,match_E2
web1.corp,match_E2
web2.corp,match_E2
```

Comment: Thanks @pormulsys, i am looking one line command either awk/grep/or combination of both. btw, there are two matching strings (match_E2 and pattern_2)  as mentioned in expected output.

Answer (score 1):

This does full, literal string matching so it'll work even if your target strings contain regexp metacharacters or appear as substrings in your input:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { strs["match_E2"]; strs["pattern_2"]; FS=";"; OFS="," }
    { for (str in strs) if (index(","$NF",",","str",")) print $1, str }
' file
abcd.corp,match_E2
web1.corp,match_E2
web2.corp,match_E2
web3.corp,pattern_2
web4.corp,pattern_2
```

For an example of partial vs full matching, consider the following input:

```
$ cat file
abcd.corp;;a123,Virtual,aws,Linux,Linux,mismatch_E2,Database
web1.corp;;,Virtual,azure,match_E2,Linux,corpo,Database
web2.corp;;match_E2,Virtual,a2responsible,Linux_Suse,Linux,corpo,Database
web3.corp;;Virtual,Virtual,corpo,pattern_275,Linux,corpo,Database
web4.corp;;Virtual,Virtual,corpo,,Linux,pattern_2,Database
```

Note that now the first line of input contains `mismatch_E2` instead of `match_E2` and the 4th line is `pattern_275` instead of `pattern_2`. Now run the above awk script on it and see that it produces the expected output:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { strs["match_E2"]; strs["pattern_2"]; FS=";"; OFS="," }
    { for (str in strs) if (index(","$NF",",","str",")) print $1, str }
' file
web1.corp,match_E2
web2.corp,match_E2
web4.corp,pattern_2
```

For an example of regexp vs string matching, change the `match_E2` on line 1 to `m.*2` and `patch_2` on the 4th line to `p.*2` in the input:

```
$ cat file
abcd.corp;;a123,Virtual,aws,Linux,Linux,m.*2,Database
web1.corp;;,Virtual,azure,m.*2,Linux,corpo,Database
web2.corp;;m.*2,Virtual,a2responsible,Linux_Suse,Linux,corpo,Database
web3.corp;;Virtual,Virtual,corpo,pattern_2,Linux,corpo,Database
web4.corp;;Virtual,Virtual,corpo,,Linux,pattern_2,Database
```

and modify the above awk script to look for `m.*2` and `p.*2` instead of `match_E2` and `pattern_2` and see that again it produces the expected output:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { strs["m.*2"]; strs["p.*2"]; FS=";"; OFS="," }
    { for (str in strs) if (index(","$NF",",","str",")) print $1, str }
' file
abcd.corp,m.*2
web3.corp,p.*2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F "," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /match_E2|pattern_2/){print $1,$i}}}'  filename|sed "s/;.*[ ;]/,/g"
```

output

```
abcd.corp,match_E2
web1.corp,match_E2
web2.corp,match_E2
web3.corp,pattern_2
web4.corp,pattern_2
```